# Can't access news.reads actions using facebook open graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook account I KNOW has articles posted to the open graph as read actions under the news.reads global namespace (I can see them under the News aggregation in my timeline) but when I try to get a list of them using this api address:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/news.reads?access_token=[my access token]

it returns:

{
   "data": [

],
   "paging": {
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/news.reads?access_token=[my access token]&offset=25&limit=25"
   }
}

as though there were no articles posted at all.  I checked my permissions and cant find anything that might be causing this issue.  Anyone know how I should be accessing this data correctly?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need the `user_actions.news` [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) in order to access the user's list of news reads, otherwise the array comes back empty